# Trying to write a double-lined \ulcorner

Tags: symbols

My professor uses the symbol: [image: double line upper left corner symbol] to represent an encoding.

I tried to use Detexify and searching for the symbol in the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list, but with no luck.

Comment: your image is a bit fuzzy it looks like `\ulcorner u \urcorner` or do you mean the verticals are double struck? If you ave a PDF from your professor you can see what font it is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a group effort here.  I had the notion of overlaying two corners with a negative kern.  David suggested tightening the gap.  That is what I present below.

However, I originally used paired delimiters and campa suggests not using them to avoid other problems.  So that composite is what we now have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand\dcorn[1]{\ulcorner\mkern-7mu\ulcorner\mkern-3mu#1%
  \mkern-3mu\urcorner\mkern-7mu\urcorner}
\begin{document}
\[
\dcorn{u}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah I was about to post similar but with tighter spacing (but same 7mu over-print) `$\ulcorner\mkern-7mu\ulcorner\!u\!\urcorner\mkern-7mu\urcorner$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was thinking about the tightness too.  I will enact.

Comment: Beaten by a few seconds `:-)` I had chosen the very same value `-7mu`. However, I would not use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. This will react very badly to the starred version or optional argument.

Answer (score 0):

Picture mode to the rescue!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pict2e,color}

\newcommand{\encoding}[1]{%
  \uldoublecorner
  \mspace{0.278mu}
  #1%
  \mspace{0.278mu}
  \urdoublecorner
}

\newcommand{\uldoublecorner}{\mathopen{\udoublecorner{1}{3}}}
\newcommand{\urdoublecorner}{\mathclose{\udoublecorner{4}{6}}}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\udoublecorner}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\udoublecorner@{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\udoublecorner@}[2]{%
  \udoublecorner@@#1#2%
}
\newcommand{\udoublecorner@@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \settoheight{\unitlength}{$\m@th#1\ulcorner$}%
  \begin{picture}(0.7,1)
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.1,0.975)(0.6,0.975)
  \Line(0.#2,0.475)(0.#2,0.975)
  \Line(0.#3,0.475)(0.#3,0.975)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\encoding{u}$ $\scriptstyle\encoding{u}$

% examples with overlapping symbols and color

\leavevmode\rlap{$\ulcorner u\urcorner$}\textcolor{red}{$\encoding{u}$}

\leavevmode\rlap{$\encoding{u}$}\textcolor{red}{$\ulcorner u\urcorner$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If really needed, this could be improved by changing the line thickness in script style.